# How to match status bar and navigation bar colors to action bar and bottom navigation menu?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-statusbar, android-12

I'm attempting to match the status bar and navigation bar color to the action bar and bottom navigation menu. When I set the color to "colorOnPrimary" to match the action bar, the colors come out darker than expected.

**Changing Status bar and Navigation bar colors:**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.PATCOToday" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/material_dynamic_primary99</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/material_dynamic_primary10</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_dynamic_primary60</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_dynamic_primary50</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryContainer">@color/material_dynamic_primary90</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/material_dynamic_primary99</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimaryContainer">@color/material_dynamic_primary20</item>
    <!-- Status-bar and Nav-bar -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?android:colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">?android:colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

**[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xw51.png) vs [What I'd Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MvTH.png)**

---

I believe the colors are coming out differently because of my implementation of Material 3, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you can try to do this programmatically by inserting these lines in your *onCreate()* method in **MainActivity** class.

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.your_color));
    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.your_color));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's very helpful.